# How to record the processing of php code by the server ? how to decompile php code?

Tags: php, server, xampp, wamp, reverse-engineering

How is php code executed and how is the server processing it ?

We all know that all software becomes machine language(01).

We can also easily convert machine language(01) to assembly language.

And finally we have done the decompile operation and we can reverse engineer the software !

it's true ?!
ok!

Now php code that is encrypted by different algorithms and different software such as (zend, ioncube, ...) will eventually be converted to php code for the server to be able to process them ?!

The code that is encrypted should eventually become readable language for the server, right?

I want to know what is the process of decompile this source code on the server ?

example:

This is my code:

```
<?php

$x = 1;
$y = 2;
$sum = $x + $y;
echo $sum;
```

output:

```
3
```

To do this simple calculation, the server takes the php code and then processes it and displays the output ....

Is there a way to record the process of code processing by the server?
Like software that eventually becomes the language of the machine and we get the machine code of that software for reverse engineering !

I translated this question by google translate, I hope you understand what I mean! thanks all.

Comment: PHP is not compiled to machine language or bytecode like Java or C#. It's interpreted and executed by the PHP program at runtime. So there is no way to "decompile" if it's not compiled in the first place. For more info see https://stillat.com/blog/2014/04/02/how-does-php-work-with-the-web-server-and-browser/

Comment: Codes encrypted by different software eventually become php language?

And if so, is there a way to record these codes when running them on the server?

Comment: "Codes encrypted by different software eventually become php language?" I'm not sure what you mean by this. PHP source code is interpreted by the PHP program. Much like Javascript is interpreted by your browser. No compilation or transpilation happens. PHP is PHP and stays PHP

Comment: We encrypt our php code to protect it.

When we execute our php encrypted code, it must be decrypted by a set of keys so that it can be read and processed by the server.

We do not see this process of decoding and processing the server, and in the end we only see the output.

I want to see and record this process. And the output does not matter to me.

Comment: "We encrypt our php code to protect it" If you encrypted the code yourself, you also know how to decrypt it right?

Comment: Of course, if I write this cryptographic algorithm myself, I have the key to decrypt it.

I know that eventually the program that is running must be decrypted.

And I know that even if we do not have a decryption key, the encrypted code can be read by listening to and recording the server in decryption mode, because the server needs the original code to process the code and the encrypted code cannot be read.

Now, how do you think php code executed by the server can be recorded ?!

Comment: It can't be "recorded" because PHP INTERPRETS it at runtime instead of compiling it first

Comment: Yes you are right, but what we see is the only output returned by that code and we do not know the code itself and its algorithm, what do we have to do to get this?

Comment: This process is almost like software  reverse engineering...

Comment: The whole point of encryption is that it can't be cracked without cracking or knowing the encryption keys.

Comment: Have you ever reverse engineering software?

Comment: I have. But never PHP because it's usually open source. I did de-compile and reverse-engineer Android apps. But as you might know that's Java. Java is a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments above are muddled and not entirely accurate. This should give a little insight.

"We all know that all software becomes machine language"

Putting aside code that sits *below* machine language such as that found in CISC or EISC architectures (e.g. Linn Rekursiv from the folks that used to make record players), software may not *become* machine language but instead simply be interpreted as-is or be compiled and executed by a program implementing a virtual machine. So it may be transformed, but not necessarily to machine language.

"How is php code executed and how is the server processing it"

As of PHP 4, PHP source gets compiled to bytecode and the bytecode is executed by a virtual machine, the so-called "Zend Engine". With the outcome of compilation being deterministic, this naturally lends itself to caching, and PHP installations will often have a caching component that optimises and caches the compiled bytecode in shared memory. The cache allows the compilation step to be skipped for files that are cached and unchanged, and by ensuring that some other prerequisites related to memory addressing are met, compiled code can be executed directly from the shared memory cache with no deserialisation and minimal overhead, thus delivering a good speedup.

There are various ways that a server may trigger PHP execution, such as directly running the PHP command line program, having the PHP core linked into the web server, or PHP processes running in a pool with I/O transferred between server and PHP via some IPC mechanism.

Rather than protecting source code, protection systems such as Zend and ionCube leverage the compilation to bytecode process first by also compiling source to bytecode, and then going further to protect the bytecode in various ways, perhaps by also utilising a custom execution engine.

Bytecode systems tend to have machine instructions that are closer to the high level language they target than native machine code, with PHP bytecode having instructions to implement foreach and some other keywords directly for example. As a result, bytecode tends to be easier to decompile, and there have been decompilers for PHP since around 2006 first coming out of China and later with projects such as XCache.